# Does xml-rpc have some kind of "response length limit"?

Tags: python, plone, xml-rpc, zope

This is likely too general a question but, googlin' around for hours, I haven't found anything.

I have a web application based on zope/plone/python where zope/plone is used, among other things, as a soap and xml-rpc web server.
However sometimes (when response is "big") my xml-rpc response is truncated(*) as if the xml-rpc protocol could not handle more than "x" characters (or bytes).

Is anyone aware of this?

### Bonus question:

If you were in my shoes, what would you look for during "investigation"?

---

I've also added "python" tag because zope/plone components are written in this language and, maybe, there are some pythoners that could help me.

(*) Received to caller (that is onto another network, for example) truncated.

Comment: There is no inherent limit in either XML-RPC (the standard) or Zope. You'll have to try and reproduce the problem by connecting to each component in the chain *directly*; first to Zope, then to any servers in front, then from a remote network.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thank you for your suggest Martijn; this is exactly what I'm going to do next week

Answer (score 1):

As I know XML-RPC in general doesn't have any length limitation but lib you (or server) uses for working with XML-RPC can have limitation. As example, **libxmlrpc** has an limitation: http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/doc/libxmlrpc.html#limit

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that control characters in response content could block the parsing of the xml and, for example, just cut data. At least this is what happened to me.

Maybe I'm a little bit late, anyway I spent so much time today on this issue that I would like to share what I've finally found.

At the beginning I've tried to check if there is some limits somewhere: in xml-rpc server php code, in my apache http server, in the python xml-rpc client (base on incution xml-rpc library)... but found nothing.

Than I begun searching for hidden control characters in the response content and finally found a record separator ASCII character. Deleted and all worked well.